# Xcode tableview not displaying firebase objects

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I am currently trying to display firebase objects in my tableview. However, I am only getting empty prototype cells. Thanks if you can take a glance at it!

```
 import UIKit
import Firebase

class UsersTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var user = [User]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func getusers() {
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
let query = rootRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "fullname")
query.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        if let value = child.value as? NSDictionary {
            let userToShow = User()
            let fullname = value["fullname"] as? String ?? "Name not found"
            let uid = value["uid"] as? String ?? "uid not found"
            userToShow.fullname = fullname
            userToShow.userID = uid
             self.user.append(userToShow)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
        }
    }
}

}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return user.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = self.user[indexPath.row].fullname
    cell.userID = self.user[indexPath.row].userID
    cell.userImage.downloadImage(from: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath!)


    return cell
}

}

extension UIImageView {

@objc func downloadImage(from imgURL: String!) {
    let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}}
```

Thanks again for anyone willing to help! I am currently using Swift 4 with Google's Firebase API.

p.s. I know that I have connected delegate and dataSource. I am also sure that I have properly titled my Identifier. Thanks!

Comment: where did u call `getusers()`

Comment: That was exactly it... l'm honestly appalled that I spent this long trying to answer my own question lol. If you were to answer my question I would love give you an up-vote!

Comment: However, I am still getting an error about uploading my "urltoImage". I will most likely ask in a separate thread, but if you or anyone else has any ideas, I would love to hear.